# Embed Brightcove video into my HTML UI from Brightcove video URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, video, brightcove

I am trying to embed brightcove video into my Rails + AngularJS application.  I have video URL. I had tried with following HTML tag, But that won't work for me.
Help me to find solution.

Below is my code :

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/e1/uds/pd/57838016001/57838016001_1520916807001_Space-Galaxy.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Code shown [works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/8shyt0r5/)

Comment: ya but it's not working on my project. and i am stuck.

Comment: Well something is clearly different than what is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
<embed src="video_URL"></embed>
```